# Spring Security Access Denied

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4 and meet the following problem.

Here is the spring-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**"  access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
    <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

This is the user detail service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;    

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.models.User instance = new com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.models.User(username, null, null);
    com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.models.User domainUser = userDAO.findByExample(instance).get(0);

    List<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(domainUser.getRole()));

    User user = new User(
            domainUser.getUsername(), 
            domainUser.getPassword(), 
            setAuths
    );

    return user;

}
```

When I navigate to `/admin` page, the login page shows up. And I use the username and password  which I am sure has the role `ADMIN` because it can varified by `Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();`.

However, once I get authorized, it shows `HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied`. Which I think means the username and password is correct but there's something wrong with the role.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your role it should be ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: <intercept-url pattern="/admin**"  access="hasRole('ADMIN')" /> change to   <intercept-url pattern="/admin**"  access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" /> and change database value to ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Amazingly, it works! Why? It has to start with **ROLE_**?